# Diagonal touchpad movement results in wobbly line

Tags: linux, touchpad, thinkpad

I'm using a ThinkPad L440 with a Synaptics touchpad. A while ago (~1-2 months) the touchpad started acting strange when trying to move the mouse pointer diagonally.

[image]

The picture shows the first line drawn with an external mouse, second with the trackpoint and the last one with the touchpad.

At first I thought the issue was related to libinput or a kernel update but even after booting into older distros (like Ubuntu 14.04 without libinput and with older 3.16 kernel), the problem still prevails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be affected by something similar to [Thinkpad X220 touchpad movement is jumpy and extremely imprecise](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1264453) (libinput bug report). In essence, for some firmwares:

> [the] touchpad only sends x/y events every 50 device units. libinput has a custom acceleration method for that.

(Comment #10 in the bug report above.)

This would explain the behaviour you're seeing. I had the same experience on a ThinkPad x240 (despite the fact that the bug report targets x220), and the fix from comments #10 and #13 in that bug report solved it for me.

If this works for you it might be worth telling the libinput people so they extend the "custom acceleration method" to more firmwares.